# Best way to handle movement input?

Tags: c++, state

I'm currently developing a RPG movement system in c++, and tried to use the State Pattern/State machine for this, but AFAIK I would have to check each movement key in every state.(right?)

Is there a better design for this?, because the states have no restriction, the player can switch to any move state at any time.

can anyone help

Answer (score 1):

How about implementing a stack of states rather than a single state machine? Events and callbacks (updating, input, drawing, etc.) are sent to the topmost state. If they're unhandled, they're passed to the next state, etc.

For example, your character only has the `IdleState` on its stack. This handles movement as well.

So if the player hits a directional key, this adds another state, e.g. `MoveNorthState`. This state will handle the transition/animation and remove itself once done.

Let's assume there's a toggle to make your character take flight. So once you hit the hotkey, the state `FlightState` is added. `FlightState` won't handle movement, so input events related to movement are passed down the stack to `IdleState`, which will once again add a state, e.g. `MoveSouthState`.

If your `FlightState` notices the hotkey for state change to be hit, it will remove itself from the stack and pass control back to the state below (typically `IdleState`).

Of course this has other potential problems, like trying to modify some state in the middle. You'll have to come up with proper states and flags/status fields. Don't create a state for every tiny bit, just because you're able to.